# Why can't I access "fullName" from my object

Tags: javascript, class, javascript-objects

```
class PersonCl {
  constructor(fullName, birthYear) {
    this.fullName = fullName;
    this.birthYear = birthYear;
  }

  // Methods will be added tp .prototype property
  calcAge() {
    console.log(2037 - this.birthYear);
  }

  get age() {
    return 2037 - this.birthYear;
  }
  set fullName(name) {
    if (name.includes(' ')) this._fullName = name;
    else alert(`${name} is not a full name`);
  }
}

const jessica = new PersonCl('jessica Davis', 1996);
```

I made an class and try to set the setter of exact name so it shows me error "maximize call stack" and now I changed the variable name but the original "firstName" is missing I know you can fix it with with the getter but I want to know what the reason behind it. I don't need a solution I need an explanation.

Comment: Because you can't get two properties with the same name. `this.fullName` refers to the setter function, you can't also create a string with that name

Comment: @Konrad wrong, the setter is defined before the constructor so it's called not overwritten

Comment: The error is likely something about reaching the maximum call stack, not "maximize call stack" which is something different.

Comment: @HereticMonkey thanks brother for editing my post my English is not great

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I guess you defined the getter as:

```
get fullName() { return this.fullName; }
```

That's why there was a recursive call because the getter calls itself.

To access without the getter you need to retrieved the assigned private variable `this._fullName`:

Regarding the `this.fullName = fullName` in the constructor. The setter is defined before the constructor's call, so it's NOT assigning a new property bur rather a call of the setter.

```js
class PersonCl {
  constructor(fullName, birthYear) {
    this.fullName = fullName;
    this.birthYear = birthYear;
  }

  // Methods will be added tp .prototype property
  calcAge() {
    console.log(2037 - this.birthYear);
  }

  get age() {
    return 2037 - this.birthYear;
  }
  get fullName(){
    console.log('retrieved with a getter');
    return this._fullName;
  }
  set fullName(name) {
    if (name.includes(' ')) this._fullName = name;
    else alert(`${name} is not a full name`);
  }
}

const jessica = new PersonCl('jessica Davis', 1996);

console.log(jessica.fullName);

// get it without a getter
console.log(jessica._fullName);
```

To overwrite the property (not assign a value!) you need to use `Object.defineProperty()`:

```js
class PersonCl {
  constructor(fullName, birthYear) {
    Object.defineProperty(this, 'fullName', {value: fullName});
    this.birthYear = birthYear;
  }

  // Methods will be added tp .prototype property
  calcAge() {
    console.log(2037 - this.birthYear);
  }

  get age() {
    return 2037 - this.birthYear;
  }
  set fullName(name) {
    if (name.includes(' ')) this._fullName = name;
    else alert(`${name} is not a full name`);
  }
}

const jessica = new PersonCl('jessica Davis', 1996);

console.log(jessica.fullName);
```

Comment: i know alexendar but i just wanna know the reason i wrote in a post that i know you can get it by getter but why the fullName is not showing even though i explicitly write this.fullName = fullName; ( pardon my english)

Comment: @BilalZahidShah because it's a call of the setter, not overwriting the property. the property has a setter, so it's called always when you do `object.property = value`.

Comment: gotcha gothca so its was a property and after that i converted to a method so thats why i could'nt see it in console THANKS BROTHER

Comment: done brother did that before your asking